# How to user dapper to map a simple stored procedure in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, stored-procedures, dapper

My Stored Procedure just returns a `string`. Eg: This stored procedure returns `"en-US"`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_GetStringConfig](  
  @iCode CHAR(20))  
AS  
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON  

  SELECT Value  
  FROM  T_SReq_Config WITH (NOLOCK)  
  WHERE Code = @iCode  

  IF @@ERROR <> 0  
  RETURN @@ERROR  

  RETURN 0  
END
```

I am using `Dapper` like this:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
            {
                var result = connection.Query<ModelClass>(
                                                    "P_GetStringConfig",
                                                    new {@iCode = "MCode"},
                                                    commandType:     CommandType.StoredProcedure).First();
            }
```

where my `ModelClass` is

```
class ModelClass
{
  string result {get;set;}
}
```

But getting `null`.

Any ideas what am I missing here ? (or is there any other method to call this ?)

Comment: Yes, it should be "P_GetStringConfig" in the dapper query method, or was that just a typo in this question but not in your actual code?

Comment: @Dirk: Sorry, it was a `typo`. Updated the question.

Comment: Do you want the the result of the select query or the result of the return statement?

Comment: @Dirk: Interested with just the return value (in this SP, it returns  just a `string` value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you should have your property result named as the field returned by the SP (value) but this creates a conflict with a reserved keyword

So, change the SP to rename the field returned as the property of your model

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[P_GetStringConfig](  
  @iCode CHAR(20))  
AS  
BEGIN  
  SET NOCOUNT ON  

  SELECT Value AS result
  FROM  T_SReq_Config WITH (NOLOCK)  
  WHERE Code = @iCode  

  IF @@ERROR <> 0  
  RETURN @@ERROR  

  RETURN 0  
END
```

Also, I suggest to change the code to use FirstOrDefault in case your SP doesn't find anything your code will raise an Exception

```
 var result = connection.Query<ModelClass>("P_GetStringConfig",
                                            new {@iCode = "MCode"},
                                            commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure)
                                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you. Gonna try that now. BTW, the `Query<T>` always returns a `List<T>` ? Will it now return just a `T`? Because, the `SP` just returns a simple `string` value ?

Comment: @nowhewhomustnotbenamed if all you want is a single string value, then `Query<string>(...).SingleOrDefault()` would work perfectly well, and **it doesn't matter what the column name is**. One caveat there: you won't be able to tell the difference between "no row" and "one row with a null value"